# Exclusively assign value to common variable

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript, ag-grid

Hi I have the following function,

```
private _setupTimeDayVal(days:any, times: any, data?: any){
        let timeData: Array<any> = [];
        for (let x in times){
            let timing: any = {};
            for (let y in days){
              if (days[y] == 'time'){
                  timing[days[y]] = (typeof days[y] != 'undefined') ?  times[x] : undefined;
                  timeData.push(timing);
                  this._rowResult = this._agSvc.setRowResult(timeData);
              }else {
                  this._rowResult = this._agSvc.setRowResult(data);
              }
            }
        }
        this._gridOptions.rowData = this._rowResult;
    }
```

The function takes in 3 parameters. Am checking whether one of the value in days array is `time`, it is one of the column in my table (ag-grid), then I create an object and push to empty array and assign it into a variable named `_rowResult`.

And at the end of the loop I assign the `_rowResult` value into my common variable named `this._gridOptions.rowData` which am used to pass as data into my table(ag-grid).

But its always passing me the `else` statement data(used to to add value to my other columns except the time column), `this._rowResult = this._agSvc.setRowResult(data);`.

But I want to improve this code so that my time column will be filled with the if statement data and other columns need to fill with the else statement. Any idea guys? Thanks in advance.

Comment: First, `for..in` over arrays is a bad idea. Use `for` instead. Also can you share sample data for `times` and `days`?

Comment: times is an array of time values from "00:00" to "24:00" and days is Array of day strings

Comment: [This answer explains why `for...in` loops are bad for arrays](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9329476/6806381)